# PDF to PPT converter in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04, libreoffice

i am convert pdf to ppt using this command `libreoffice --headless --convert-to ppt exaam.pdf`, in libre office working fine but not open in Microsoft power point, it's `can't read outline file filename` error.
please help me.
Any good suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: You can easily convert most document formats (like .doc, .ppt) into a PDF by printing to a PDF.  The process is lossy and one-way.  A PDF just describes how a document should appear on a page.  You can't convert a generic PDF into a powerpoint, because a PDF doesn't track/store the same layout information that a PPT would need.  (You probably could write a program that captures every page of a PDF and  inserts it as a slide in a PDF, but the text, etc in the PDF wouldn't be editable).  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format

Comment: If you need to edit a PDF that you have, your best bet is to use PDF editing software.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not possible is because PDF files are opened in Draw, and you can't export Draw documents to PPT (you can only export to PPT from Impress).

Actually you even get an error message telling you exactly that:

```
$ libreoffice --convert-to ppt test.pdf
Error: no export filter for /path/to/test.ppt found, aborting.
Error: no export filter
```

The closest you can do is to open the PDF in Draw, and copy&paste the content of each & every Draw page to an Impress slide. Probably it won't be perfect, but it'll be at least editable. If you don't need editable content, you can just covert the pages of the PDF to bitmaps and insert the bitmaps in Impress.